Why does Intel x86 manual use +rd instead of +ro or +rq for 64-bit registers?
The description of the PUSH instruction in the Intel manual (PDF, Volume 2, Chapter 4.3, PUSH) contains the line 50+rd    PUSH r64. It seems +rd is used throughout most of the instruction descriptions for both 32-bit and 64-bit registers. However, according to Table 3-1. Register Codes Associated With +rb, +rw, +rd, +ro, +rd refers to 32-bit registers and +ro to 64-bit ones.
Additionally, the columns for the two widths are different. +rd contains ESP, EBP, ESI, EDI twice while +ro has N/A in their place.
Is this an oversight in the manual or is there some deeper meaning behind it?
The AMD manual (PDF, Volume 3, Chapter 3, PUSH) uses +rq for 64-bit registers when describing instructions using them. My confusion is twofold:

The q in +rq seems to mean quadword which is consistent with 64-bit width. Is there any reason intel uses +ro?
Why are some lines repeated in table 3-1 for 32-bit registers and why are they not repeated for 64-bits?

I am tempted to just assume this is an error in the Intel manual and follow AMD's descriptions but I want to double check.

In fact, +ro doesn't seem to appear anywhere in the manual except in that table.  It's not listed in the encoding for any instruction, unless formatted in some other way that my PDF search didn't find.

I think the "repeated lines" is just awkward fomatting of the table, an artifact of there not really being a good one-to-one correspondence between the registers of different sizes.  It doesn't mean anything as far as I can tell.  If you treat the "quadword register" columns as its own independent table and ignore the N/A lines, its contents make sense.
